# Using state in other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am learning and new to react and I want to know how to pass state from one component to other,

I have one component as

```
const [paneCount, setPaneCount]= useState(1);

const openPane = (paneKey) => {
  setOpeningPaneKeys(oldState => {
    if (!oldState.includes(paneKey)) {
      return [...oldState, paneKey]
    }
    return oldState
  })
  setPaneCount(paneCount+1);
  console.log(paneCount);

  setFocusingPaneKey(paneKey)
}
```

where I want to use paneCount in App.js file

```
function App(props) {

const [inactive, setInactive] = useState(false);

return (
<div className="App">
  
  <Header />
  <Navbar 
      onCollapse={(inactive) => {
        setInactive(!inactive);
      }}
    />

  <div class="landing-card">
    <div>
      
      <h4 class="headingStyle">Recorder Box</h4>
      <h4>Count:{props.paneCount}</h4>
      <img src="landing.jpg" alt="Forest" width="775" height="500"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How to pass paneCount to App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass data upwards, only downwards. The reason for that is how the application and data flow is built. Luckily there are 3 ways to get it done.

**1) Initialize in App.js**

If you want to use state value in `App.js` but want to work with it somewhere else:

```
export default function App() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState();

  return <Component state={ myState } setState={ setMyState } />
}
```

This way you can keep all your state in 1 place and use it everywhere, but it also means that you have to pass component by component to do so.

**2) Context**

This improves the previous option, because you no longer need to pass data around. Instead you can keep it in a provider and use it throughout your application.

There are multiple ways to define a provider, so I will just [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) you the docs for that one.

*Note: Provider definitions does not differ in any way. They are not practical or impractical, simply one's preference over another!*

**3) Redux**

This is arguably the **BEST** option for state management (eventhough I don't like it..). I haven't used it yet and don't want to either, because the previous option does the same with less effort IMO.

Here's the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start) for that one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing paneCount to App.js which I suppose is the parent component. You can create paneCount in App.js and then pass setPaneCount to the openPane component like this.

```
<openPane setPaneCount = {setPanecount} paneCount = {setPaneCount}/>
```

If you are not calling openPane in the App.js for some reason then go to the parent component that is calling both App and openPane and create and pass the setPaneCount and paneCount from there. If you making something complex instead of drilling the value down like this you might want to look at some stateManagement tools like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started/) or [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Here the openPane is not a component, it is one of the method in a component.

Comment: @UserD you can't call hook in a method. You can only call a hook either inside a functional component or other hooks please check here. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html.

Comment: can you please explain it in detail, so that I can clear the problem.